# For loop doesn't append to other json in original order

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, youtube-api

I'm trying to get information from a YouTube video. I fetch the ID from a file that looks like this:

**songlist.json**

```
 ["vbMQfaG6lo8", "07UwP3kHTTk", "gjDK4OiuIfk", "NlrK03iz74A", "E_1-oylPHjs"]
```

After that I require the file and also require the data for each id

```
var songlistshit = './static/js/songlistinfo.json'
var allSongs = require('./static/js/songlist.json')    
for(var i = 0; i < allSongs.length; i++) {
    var ytId = allSongs[i]
    request("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=" + ytId + "&key=API_KEY%20&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status", function (error, response, body) {
        var sd = JSON.parse(body);
        var xd = sd.items[0].snippet.title
        var aus = sd.items[0].snippet
        name = aus.title
        tn = aus.thumbnails.default.url
        var data = '\n{"name": "' + name + '", "user": "Mstiekema", "img": "' + tn + '"},'
        fs.appendFile(songlistshit, data, 'utf8', function(err) {if (err) {return}})

    })
};
```

But when it appends to the second JSON file it loses the original order. Here's an example of how it's put into the file.

**songlistinfo.json**

```
{"name": "Enjoy The Silence by KI Theory (Ghost In The Shell Trailer Music)", "user": "Mstiekema", "img": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/E_1-oylPHjs/default.jpg"},
{"name": "Majora's Mask - Terrible Fate", "user": "Mstiekema", "img": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vbMQfaG6lo8/default.jpg"},
{"name": "Lilium Elfen Lied-エルフェンリート", "user": "Mstiekema", "img": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/07UwP3kHTTk/default.jpg"},
{"name": "MODERN PILLOW TALKING", "user": "Mstiekema", "img": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gjDK4OiuIfk/default.jpg"},
{"name": "Midna's Theme on Guitar", "user": "Mstiekema", "img": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/NlrK03iz74A/default.jpg"},
```

But it shouldn't be in this order. The order should be the following:

**songlistinfo.json**

```
{"name": "Majora's Mask - Terrible Fate", "user": "Mstiekema", "img": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vbMQfaG6lo8/default.jpg"},
{"name": "Lilium Elfen Lied-エルフェンリート", "user": "Mstiekema", "img": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/07UwP3kHTTk/default.jpg"},
{"name": "MODERN PILLOW TALKING", "user": "Mstiekema", "img": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gjDK4OiuIfk/default.jpg"},
{"name": "Midna's Theme on Guitar", "user": "Mstiekema", "img": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/NlrK03iz74A/default.jpg"},
{"name": "Enjoy The Silence by KI Theory (Ghost In The Shell Trailer Music)", "user": "Mstiekema", "img": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/E_1-oylPHjs/default.jpg"},
```

(I know that the songlistinfo.json file doesn't contain the correct JSON structure, but I'll fix that after fixed the order issue.)

Comment: You might want to remove the part where you api key in included in the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing to the file asynchronusly, it is writing to the file in the order the requests finish, not all of them are going to finish on time. You can solve this by using a rescursive function rather than a for loop.

```
requestVideoInfo(0);

function requestVideoInfo(count) {
  if(count < allSongs.length) {
    ytId = allSongs[count]
    request("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=" + ytId + "&key=API_KEY%20&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status", function (error, response, body) {
      var sd = JSON.parse(body);
      var xd = sd.items[0].snippet.title
      var aus = sd.items[0].snippet
      name = aus.title
      tn = aus.thumbnails.default.url
      var data = '\n{"name": "' + name + '", "user": "Mstiekema", "img": "' + tn + '"},'
      fs.appendFile(songlistshit, data, 'utf8', function(err) {
        if (err)
          console.log('Error', e);
        else
          requestVideoInfo(++count);

      // start to request the next video into once this one is done
      })
    })
  }
}
```

However you could see a negative performance impact on your code beacuse you are no longer making multiple calls at once, and losing the benifet of the callback nature of `request`.

Answer (score 0):

The order is propably not correct because you are using async requests that does not have to be finished in the same order as you called them.

For example depending on request time to youtube your callbacks may run in different order every time. You'd have to either use some library like Bluebird with `all` method that would process all promises(first you'd have to convert `request` method to return promise or use Bluebird `promisify` method) and then you would get the list of responses in the same order you called the requests.

Or you can manually create an array of responses and after all of them will be processed you can reorder them with some alghoritm to have the same order as your JSON.

The key fact is that async functions called in loop are not guaranteed to resolve in the same order as you called them :)